# qvariant_cast with custom type

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I have this class, register it to use as QVariant

```
class MyTimeLine
{
public:
   MyTimeLine(double kStart = 0, double kEnd = 1);
   void paint(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect,
              const QPalette &palette)const;
private:
   double _kStartTime;
   double _kEndTime;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyTimeLine)
```

Then i convert it in QVariant, and when i want use qvariant_cast and get MyTimeLine object  i get object, created by default constructor

```
myTask->setData(2,Qt::UserRole,
QVariant::fromValue(MyTimeLine(a,b)));

MyTimeLine taskTimeLine = qvariant_cast<MyTimeLine>(index.data());
//taskTimeLine._kStartTime = 0;
//taskTimeLine._kEndTime = 1;
```

Comment: Maybe your `index.data()` returns such object?

Comment: Thanks, i forgot specify role, index.data(Qt::UserRole) return what i want

Comment: `qRegisterMetaType` missed

Answer (score 2):

Are your sure the index.data() can be converted to MyTimeLine ?

```
T qvariant_cast ( const QVariant & value )
```

Returns the given value converted to the template type T.
This function is equivalent to QVariant::value().

```
T QVariant::value () const
```

Returns the stored value converted to the template type T. Call canConvert() to find out whether a type can be converted. **If the value cannot be converted, default-constructed value will be returned.**